# How do you install sauerbraten?

Tags: games

How do you install sauerbraten on Ubuntu 14.04?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You run `sudo apt-get install sauerbraten`.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are a new user @ilikepie1234.

In the case you don't understand what spacegeek224 meant, press

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

This will open a command line window. This is where spacegeek224's answer comes in. Just copy and paste

```
sudo apt-get install sauerbraten
```

onto the new terminal window you just opened, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Then enter your password, and bingo, there you have sauerbraten installed

Answer (score 0):

Click [here](http://apt//sauerbraten) to install it now.

Or 
Open Terminal by **Ctrl**+**Alt**+**T**
and type in:-

```
 sudo apt-get update&&sudo apt-get install sauerbraten
```